# What is the PyQt Equivalent to WinForms Activated Event?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a small PyQt application that needs to run a few checks before the application starts and if any of the checks fail, the application needs to inform the user it can't run and then quit.

In WinForms. I can achieve this simply:

```
var form = new Form();
form.Activated += (s, e) =>
{
    var condition = true;
    if (condition)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("oh dear, something's wrong.");
        Application.Exit();
    }
};
```

PyQt doesn't seem to have a signal that can be connected to when the main application window has loaded and my current attempts don't even fire off the dialog when the condition fails.

This is what I have at the moment (MRE(. Program flow is as follows:

```
import sys
import winreg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,  QMessageBox

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    def loadData(self):
        try:
            key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Path\To\Nonexistant\Key')
            x = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'some_key')[0]
            print(x)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            error.setText('Cannot locate installation directory.')
            error.setWindowTitle('Cannot find registry key')
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error.show()
            QApplication.quit()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    main_window.loadData()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

My end goal is to be able to let `loadData()` run when the application has loaded fully and is displayed to the user.

Update: Program now works as expected. I had to:

- Change `error.show()` to `error.exec_()`
- Change `QApplication.quit()` to `sys.exit()`
- Call `main_window.loadData()` after `main_window.show()`

Comment: From what I understand you (I don't know winforms), you want the application to end after the user clicks OK on the QMessageBox, am I correct?

Comment: That's right. Once the application loads, i need it to perform the checks and if it fails, show the QMessageBox and then quit.

I can't get the QMessageBox to display at all at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The show method is not blocking, so as soon as it is executed, the QMessageBox will be displayed at `QApplication.quit()`, instead you should use `exec_()` that will wait until the user closes the QMessageBox through the buttons.

```
# ...
error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
# error.show()
error.exec_()
QApplication.quit()
```

---

**Update:**

On the other hand, QApplication.quit() cannot be used when the eventloop is not started yet, so the solution in this case is to remove the application a moment later using QTimer.singleShot():

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    # UI stuff omitted...

    def loadData(self):
        try:
            key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Path\To\Key')
            path = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'install_path')[0]
            # I'll do stuff with path here...
        except FileNotFoundError:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            error.setText('Cannot locate directory.')
            error.setWindowTitle('Cannot find registry key')
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error.exec_()
            QTimer.singleShot(0, QApplication.quit)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    main_window.loadData()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another equivalent code is as follows

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    # UI stuff omitted...

    def loadData(self):
        try:
            key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Path\To\Key')
            path = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'install_path')[0]
            # I'll do stuff with path here...
        except FileNotFoundError:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            error.setText('Cannot locate directory.')
            error.setWindowTitle('Cannot find registry key')
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
            error.exec_()
            QApplication.quit()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    QTimer.singleShot(0, main_window.loadData)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ok, that's solved one half of the problem, but after clicking OK the application is still loading up. How do I solve that?

Comment: @Jake I recommend you **add an edition**, and do **not overwrite the code** since if you do it then my answer will not make sense. On the other hand you must provide a [MRE] since there is something that is probably generating the problem but unfortunately we do not know.

Comment: That's worked a treat, the second examples feels a bit more 'winforms-like' to me.

Comment: @eyllanesc since QMessageBox can be executed even if the application is not started, shouldn't it be better to just return True if `loadData` is successful and execute the app in that case?

Comment: @musicamante The OP wants the window to be displayed first (not the QMessageBox), in addition the OP seems to have a project structure that I did not want to change but it is also a valid option.